# How do I connect a device with a lighting connect to an iPad Pro that has a USB-C connector?

Tags: iphone, ipad, usb, lightning

I have a device that was connected to an iPhone through a iOS Lighting Cable. The iPad Pro has a USB C connector.

[image]

How do I connect my device with a lighting connector to an iPad Pro that has a USB-C connector?
[image]

I've seen a few adapters but they claim only to support charging or audio but not data.

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07KY4W9BF](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07KY4W9BF)

Comment: I have an Apple Pencil gen 1 and it comes with a female-to-female adapter that allows me to charge my pencil using a lightning cable connected to the power socket. Maybe this a kind of adapter that solves your problem.

Answer (score -1):

i recommend to use USB-C to Lightning Cable. Using Adapter isn't great idea especially if you want to synchronize data with Computer (iTunes).

Here's link: https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MX0K2AM/A/usb-c-to-lightning-cable-1-m

Comment: It requires a female lightning port on the device, which is generally not the case. Try using C-L cable with the dual female lighning adapter coming with Apple Pencil gen 1.